# Datatables error Undefined index Codeigniter

Tags: sql, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I have been using datatables before but this is the first time I encountered this type of error.

I have errors:

```
Message: Undefined index: order
Message: Undefined index: start
Message: Undefined index: length

Message: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean

Line: 253
```

(I just shortcut the errors)

My ajax code:

```
var dataTable = $('#table-grid').DataTable({ // *** This is for Data Table
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    columnDefs: [
        { orderable: false, targets: [6,5]},
        { class: "text-center", targets: [5,6]},
    ],
    "ajax":{
        url :base_url+"LandClient/view_properties", // json datasource
        type: "post",  // method  , by default get
        data: {'email': $('#email').val()},
        error: function(){  // error handling
            $(".table-grid-error").html("");
            $("#table-grid").append('<tbody class="table-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="5">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
            $("#table-grid_processing").css("display","none");
        }
    }
});
```

My controller:

```
public function view_properties(){
    $email = $this->session->userdata('login_email');
    generate_json($this->LandClientModel->view_properties($email));
}
```

My model:

```
public function view_properties($email){
    // storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
    $requestData= $_REQUEST;


    $columns = array( 
        // datatable column index  => database column name for sorting
            0 => 'pr.date_created',
            1 => 'dc.tdn_no',
            2 => 'oct.orig_cert_no,tct.orig_cert_no',
            3 => 'tct_no',
            4 => 'owner_name',
            5 => 'pr.status',
        );

    // getting total number records without any search

    $sql = "SELECT *,oct.orig_cert_no as oct1, tct.orig_cert_no as oct2  FROM land_property pr 
            LEFT JOIN land_property_orig_title oct ON pr.prop_id = oct.prop_id
            LEFT JOIN land_property_transfer_title tct ON pr.prop_id = tct.prop_id
            LEFT JOIN land_property_declaration dc ON pr.prop_id = dc.prop_id
            WHERE pr.email = ? ";
    $params = array($email);
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    $totalData = $query->num_rows();

    $totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.





    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']) ) //email address
    { 
        $sql.=" AND tdn_no LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']))."%' ";
    }

    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']) ) //email address
    { 
        $sql.=" AND oct.orig_cert_no LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']))."%' OR tct.orig_cert_no LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']))."%' ";
    }


    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']) ) //email address
    { 
        $sql.=" AND owner_name LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']))."%' ";
    }


    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']) ) //email address
    { 
        $sql.=" AND tct_no LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']))."%' ";
    }



    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    $totalFiltered = $query->num_rows(); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result.

     $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";  // adding length


    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    $data = array();

    foreach( $query->result_array() as $row ) {  // preparing an array for table tbody
        $nestedData=array(); 
        // $nestedData[] = $row["date_created"];
            if($row['tdn_no']==''){
                $tdn = "<h1>-</h1>";
            } else {
                $tdn = $row['tdn_no'];
            }
            $nestedData[] = $tdn;
            if($row['oct1']!=""){
                $nestedData[] = $row["oct1"];
            } else {
                $nestedData[] = $row["oct2"];
            }
            $nestedData[] = $row["tct_no"]==""?"-":$row["tct_no"];
            $nestedData[] = $row["owner_name"];


            if($row["status"] == 4){
                $status = "<span class='badge badge-danger tbl-badge'>Hold</span>";
            }
            elseif($row["status"] == 1){
                    $status = "<span class='badge badge-success tbl-badge'>Assessed</span>";
            }
             elseif($row["status"] == 2){
                    $status = "<span class='badge badge-warning tbl-badge'>For Assessment</span>";
            }
            $nestedData[] = $status;

            $nestedData[] = $row["status"];




            $nestedData[] = '<button class="btn btn-primary btnView btnView-1 btn-cus" > View</button>  ';
            $data[] = $nestedData;
    }
    $json_data = array(
        "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
        "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
        "data"            => $data,   // total data array
    );

    return $json_data;
}
```

btw, line 253 is

```
 $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";  // adding length
```

Comment: check my answer and change your code for solution

Answer (score 0):

The only use of `result_array` in the code you show is this line

```
foreach( $query->result_array() as $row )
```

Which, to me, means the error is saying "You are trying to use the boolean `$query` as an object that has member functions."

It seems then that this line

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
```

assigned a value of `false` to `$query`. We know it's `false` because, for a "read" statement, `query()` will return either a database result object on success or `FALSE` if the query fails.  (Note: "success" doesn't mean there are any rows, only that things didn't blow up.)

Which is all just a very long-winded way of saying your query statement doesn't work.

Based on the "Undefined index" errors my best guess is that you're attempting to get items from `$requestData` that don't exist. Those appear to be the ones for setting the `ORDER BY` clause; `$requestData['order']`, `$requestData['start']` and `$requestData['length']`.

I think you would be better off using the input class method `post_get()` [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post_get) (or `get_post()` ) instead of making a copy of `$_REQUEST`. It's not clear to me what the various indexes are that you're trying to access so I cannot offer a clear example of how to use `get_post()`.

Possibly part of the problem is trying to build a query string the old fashion way - concatenating strings based on cascading conditionals. This use case is exactly what [Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class) was made for.

Answer (score 0):

check first that variable or kay that is set or not using `isset` function like this

```
if(isset($requestData['order'][0]['column']) && isset($requestData['order'][0]['dir']) && isset($requestData['start']) && isset($requestData['length'])){
     $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";  // adding length
    }
```

check in your code eveerywhere

```
public function view_properties($email){
    // storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
    $requestData= $_REQUEST;

    $columns = array( 
        // datatable column index  => database column name for sorting
            0 => 'pr.date_created',
            1 => 'dc.tdn_no',
            2 => 'oct.orig_cert_no,tct.orig_cert_no',
            3 => 'tct_no',
            4 => 'owner_name',
            5 => 'pr.status',
        );

    // getting total number records without any search

    $sql = "SELECT *,oct.orig_cert_no as oct1, tct.orig_cert_no as oct2  FROM land_property pr 
            LEFT JOIN land_property_orig_title oct ON pr.prop_id = oct.prop_id
            LEFT JOIN land_property_transfer_title tct ON pr.prop_id = tct.prop_id
            LEFT JOIN land_property_declaration dc ON pr.prop_id = dc.prop_id
            WHERE pr.email = ? ";
    $params = array($email);
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    $totalData = $query->num_rows();

    $totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.

    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']) ) //email address
    { 
        $sql.=" AND tdn_no LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']))."%' ";
    }

    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']) ) //email address
    { 
        $sql.=" AND oct.orig_cert_no LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']))."%' OR tct.orig_cert_no LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']))."%' ";
    }

    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']) ) //email address
    { 
        $sql.=" AND owner_name LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']))."%' ";
    }

    if( !empty($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']) ) //email address
    { 
        $sql.=" AND tct_no LIKE '%". $this->db->escape_like_str(sanitize($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']))."%' ";
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    $totalFiltered = $query->num_rows(); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result.

    if(isset($requestData['length'])){
     $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";  // adding length
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    $data = array();

    foreach( $query->result_array() as $row ) {  // preparing an array for table tbody
        $nestedData=array(); 
        // $nestedData[] = $row["date_created"];
            if($row['tdn_no']==''){
                $tdn = "<h1>-</h1>";
            } else {
                $tdn = $row['tdn_no'];
            }
            $nestedData[] = $tdn;
            if($row['oct1']!=""){
                $nestedData[] = $row["oct1"];
            } else {
                $nestedData[] = $row["oct2"];
            }
            $nestedData[] = $row["tct_no"]==""?"-":$row["tct_no"];
            $nestedData[] = $row["owner_name"];

            if($row["status"] == 4){
                $status = "<span class='badge badge-danger tbl-badge'>Hold</span>";
            }
            elseif($row["status"] == 1){
                    $status = "<span class='badge badge-success tbl-badge'>Assessed</span>";
            }
             elseif($row["status"] == 2){
                    $status = "<span class='badge badge-warning tbl-badge'>For Assessment</span>";
            }
            $nestedData[] = $status;

            $nestedData[] = $row["status"];

            $nestedData[] = '<button class="btn btn-primary btnView btnView-1 btn-cus" > View</button>  ';
            $data[] = $nestedData;
    }
    $json_data = array(
        "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
        "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
        "data"            => $data,   // total data array
    );

    return $json_data;
}
```